# Move document to folder in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a document library to which I have full permissions. There is a document and a folder in the library. I want to move the document into the folder. How do you do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the root of the document library select Actions -> "Open in Windows Explorer" and drag and drop or cut and paste as you normally would.

Sorry, just saw this was 2010. It's under the Library tab. Open with Explorer.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see "Actions", where is it in share point 2010?
This was all so easy in 2007.

Comment: I edited my answer. Sorry for that. It is located under the Library tab on the Ribbon.

Comment: It isn't there - in the ribbon, under library tools I click library...

Comment: Sorry it is there - just greyed out

Comment: Here's a capture...

http://www.glowfoto.com/static_image/02-083451L/4854/jpg/07/2010/img4/glowfoto

Comment: That's quite odd. I cannot imagine why it would be inactive.

Comment: oh well, gives me something to investigate.

Comment: This is because you need to use 32-bit IE.

Comment: Cool, good information to have!

Answer (score 0):

You probably found this out already but although it's greyed out in Chrome it is active in IE. Guess it's just not support in non MS browsers?

Comment: MS did extensive testing with Firefox so if you are not going to be using IE with your SP installation, it is best to use Firefox, not Chrome, Opera, etc.